# windows CMD take a part of a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

A variable (for example: `%TAG%`) has the following content:

```
Ticket/Ticket_5761
```

I want to take the last part after the last `/` and make a new folder out of it.

The following does not work:

```
md %TAG%\
```

This creates a folder `Ticket` with a subfolder `Ticket_5761`.

Only one folder `Ticket_5761` should be created.

Further info: `%TAG%` can also be e. g. `Error/Error_5761` or `Error/controller_error/Error_5761`.
The batch should always take the content after the last `/` and create a folder out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work, in command prompt:

```cmd
for %I in ("%TAG:/=\%") do md "%~nxI"
```

Or in a batch file:

```cmd
for %%I in ("%TAG:/=\%") do md "%%~nxI"
```